# Net.Sockets, WCF or ASP.NET for a real-time chat

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, system.net.sockets

I want to implement my idea, develop an application that will have client/server sides and make connection of clients to server, so they will be able to transfer messages in real-time.

So i will develop using C#, but the question is : what should i use? I dont know what method will be better for that chat.
I need to choose between Net.Sockets, WCF and ASP.NET. So I ask you to help me with choise. If I use ASP.NET, I'll have to play with selfhost things, because I don't want to create a site, or something like this to use chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let's start from your variants

1. Net.Sockets are too low level. It's hard to make acceptable protocol. But you can use existing protocol - WebSockets. There is a tutorial how to write websocket server on c#: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server
2. Possibly, if you choose WCF, you can try to use WCF duplex persistent connection over netTcpBinding. It's easily to make self-hosting WCF-service. But WCF is complex and I think it's significant overhead for simple tasks. Also, as I know duplex connection works by using long polling, which wastes a lot of resources. Choose this variant carefully.
3. ASP.NET. If you are talking about MVC or Web Api you should use long polling, which wastes a lot of resources and isn't real realtime

There are another variant - ASP.NET SignalR (which works using WebSockets)

1. Here you can look how to write client: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client
2. And here you can find tutorial on self-hosting of SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comment: 1. Yeah, I'm sorry i was asking about WebSockets.
2. I wish that this project will grow from a simple task in something big, so I make a choose thinking about present and future. ^_^
3. So what's the difference between simple WebSocket and WebSocket using SignalR.

Tell me what you'd choose to work with for this task.

Comment: @Max SignalR is just an framework over Websockets. I definitely will choose SignalR as prooven solution. If I will got some problems with SignalR that's easy to write custom solution over Websockets. Also SignalR supports another transports (when WebSockets are not supported by client it's will be useful). Also look at the hubs functionality: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client - it's already implemented for you

Answer (score 0):

As @nsinreal mentioned, SignalR is probably the best way to go here.

There's plenty of examples on the net - here's one that'll get you going :

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

It's for a chat application, no less :)